# WebRTC: didOpenDataChannel never called, RTCDataChannel not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc, rtcdatachannel

It "seems" to be quite simple to use data channels... I already have many peers which correctly share audio and video (after the ice candidates exchange phase).

On one peer I execute the following lines:

```
RTCDataChannelConfiguration *config = [[RTCDataChannelConfiguration alloc] init];
config.channelId = 1000;
RTCDataChannel *dataChannel = [self.remotePeerConnection dataChannelForLabel:@"testDataChannel" configuration:config];
[dataChannel setDelegate:self];
```

On the same peer's device, I expect to be notified on the just set delegate when the state changes to `RTCDataChannelStateOpen`.

On the other device, instead, I expect to be notified on the `RTCPeerConnectionDelegate`, specifically on the method

```
- peerConnection:(RTCPeerConnection *)peerConnection
didOpenDataChannel:(RTCDataChannel *)dataChannel
```

Nothing of all this happens... on the first device, the dataChannel's state remains on `RTCDataChannelStateConnecting`. If I try to create another data channel with the same identifier the app crashes; so I think it really creates the data channel, but for an unknown reason it does not succeed in opening it. May someone explain what is wrong in this process?

Comment: Do you create the dataChannel before creating an offer? Because I think you should.

Comment: All peers are already exchanging video and audio. At one point one of them may choose to create a data channel. I would like other peers to see this new data channel...

Comment: If I understand correctly you need to renegotiate if you add a datachannel mid-call, same as when a new peer connects, so create a datachannel then go through the whole offer answer ice sequence again.

Comment: Ok, assume now I create the dataChannel before the offer answer sequence. I see in the sdpOffer and in the sdpAnswer information about video, audio and data (previously I saw just video and audio information). Why I can't be called on dataChannelDidChangeState? My data channel remains on the state "Connecting"... (thanks for your help)

Comment: You also need to set internalSctpDataChannels : true and DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement : true as optional constraints when creating your peerconnection.

Comment: Any updates? I'm having the same issue and no solution found at all.

Comment: Nothing :( I'm sorry